# CreateRemoteThreadEx and NtCreateThreadEx fails

Tags: winapi, process, rust

I'm currently trying to implement a Process Evasion method named [Process Doppelgänging](https://github.com/hasherezade/process_doppelganging) in Rust.

I've successfully created the NTFS transaction, the process, I've written the new parameters in the PEB of the process but I can't create the main thread.

When I attempt to create the main thread my program crash.

When I use `NtCreateThreadEx` the function returns 0xC0000022 (STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED).

(I created the process with the `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` constant and I'm running as administrator).

```
ntstatus = NtCreateThreadEx(
    &mut thread,
    THREAD_ALL_ACCESS,
    null_mut(),
    process,
    transmute::<u64, *mut c_void>(va_entrypoint),
    null_mut(),
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    null_mut()
);
```

And when I use `CreateRemoteThreadEx` the program (my program not the created process) crash with error 0xC0000005 (STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION).

```
let thread = CreateRemoteThreadEx(
    process,
    THREAD_ALL_ACCESS,
    0,
    transmute::<u64, *mut c_void>(va_entrypoint),
    null_mut(),
    0,
    null_mut(), &mut id
);
```

The `va_entrypoint` variable is equal to the `ImageBaseAddress` from the PEB of the created process + the `AddressOfEntryPoint` from the Optional Headers of the PE file that I loaded in memory.

I checked if the process is running and it's running, but I can only recognize it by it's `PID` in `tasklist.exe` output because the program doesn't have any name...

I guess it's normal because I didn't created the main thread, but I'm not sure as well.

I manually checked the address of the PEB, the Image Base address etc...With some process analysis tools and everything is ok.

I think I'm missing something when I'm trying to create the main thread — when I try to create the main thread, the process actually dies.

Comment: `transmute::<u64, *mut c_void>(va_entrypoint),` seems wrong, unless that's the point of the exploit.

Comment: Do you have functioning C++ code?

Comment: @Shepmaster It's supposed to point to the entry point of the newly created process. I defined it as: `let va_entrypoint: u64 = std::mem::transmute::<*mut winapi::ctypes::c_void, u64>(peb.ImageBaseAddress) + nt_headers.OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint as u64; `

Comment: @DavidHeffernan [Here](https://github.com/hasherezade/process_doppelganging/blob/master/main.cpp) is the official C++ code used during the presentation of the exploit. I based myself on it to build my code.

Comment: At what point does your program deviate from the working C++ code?

Comment: It doesn't, it's exactly the same thing, I use the same functions etc...The code is using `NtCreateThreadEx`, it failed for me so I tried `CreateRemoteThreadEx` and it also failed...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I've edited the question, and I answered to your question on a comment but I forgot to tag you.